# How to order split command line arguments in lexicographical order using a function?

Tags: c

I'm working on a program that takes command line arguments and splits them in half and then orders them in lexicographical order. 
For example:

hello, world!

would turn into:

he

ld!

llo

wor

I have a main method that reads through the arguments, a function that splits the arguments, and finally a function that is supposed to order the halves in lexicographical order. I can't get this to run properly because of argument type errors in the lexicographicalSort method and an incompatible pointer type in the main method. I'm having issues to correct these syntax errors, how exactly would I correct them? Also, is there anything here that would cause logical errors? This is what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int splitString(char arg[], int n)
{
   int len = strlen(arg);
   int len1 = len/2;
   int len2 = len - len1; // Compensate for possible odd length
   char *s1 = malloc(len1 + 1); // one for the null terminator
   memcpy(s1, arg, len1);
   s1[len1] = '\0';
   char *s2 = malloc(len2 + 1); // one for the null terminator
   memcpy(s2, arg + len1, len2);
   s2[len2] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n", s1);
   printf("%s\n", s2);
   free(s1);
   free(s2);

   return 0;
}

int lexicographicalSort(char *arg[], int n) 
{
    char temp[50];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        scanf("%s[^\n]",arg[i]); 

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n ; ++j)
        {
            if(strcmp(arg[i], arg[j]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, arg[i]);
                strcpy(arg[i], arg[j]);
                strcpy(arg[j], temp);
            }
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        puts(arg[i]);
    }

    return 0;   
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) 
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) 
        {
            int j = 1;
            int k = strlen(argv[i]);

            splitString(argv[i], j);
            lexicographicalSort(argv[i], j);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are going to take a pointer to a command line argument, split it and store both parts back where they came from. I don't think so.  Better `malloc` a group of 50 character blocks, (to match the size of `temp`)  and copy your half strings into those.  Then sort that list

Comment: Although why you want to do a `strcpy()` to swap whole strings instead of keeping a list of pointers and swapping them, I don't know

Comment: first thing first: when you're using allocated arrays of char (or other types), don't use the notation `*whatever[]` ; use `**whatever`. Use only the first notation when the arrays are allocated in the stack.
Also use errors flags when compiling (-Wall -Werror) it will help you on pointers/types errors.

Comment: After copying and splitting the data, `qsort` could be used with `strcmp` to easily sort the data.

Comment: `splitString` appears to allocate the strings, split it, print it, and then frees, returning 0, which is then ignored. Are you sure this contract is correct?

Comment: @NeilEdelman that is what I found to work for the time being, I'm working on getting the lexicographicalSort Method to work. I plan on cutting out any unnecessary code after the program works.

Comment: incompatible pointer type: argv[i] is a char*, not a char *arg[] which is a char**

Answer (score 1):

Basic scheme is simple. Make an array of tuples {start_pointer, length}. Do some programming on args to split the args. Fill in the array as appropriate. Make sorting with qsort, or any other sort of your choise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *s = "hello, world! . hello.....";
char *pc;
int i, n, nargs;

struct pp{
 char *p;
 int   l;
};

struct pp args[10], hargs[20];
struct pp *pargs;

int cmp(const void * v0, const void * v1) {
   struct pp *pv0 = v0, *pv1 = v1;
   return strncmp(pv0->p, pv1->p, pv0->l);
}

int main(void)
{
 for(pc = s, i = 0; *pc; ++i){
  sscanf(pc, "%*[^ ]%n", &n);
  if(n > 0){
   args[i].p = pc;
   args[i].l = n;
  }
  for(pc += n, n = 0; isspace(*pc); ++pc);
 }
 for(nargs = i, i = 0; i < nargs; ++i)
  printf("%d arg is: %.*s\n", i, args[i].l, args[i].p);
 putchar('\n');
 for(i = 0, pargs = hargs; i < nargs; ++i){
  if(args[i].l == 1){
   pargs->p = args[i].p;
   pargs->l = 1;
   pargs = pargs + 1;
  }else {
   pargs->p = args[i].p;
   pargs->l = args[i].l / 2;
   pargs = pargs + 1;
   pargs->p = args[i].p + args[i].l / 2;
   pargs->l = args[i].l - args[i].l / 2;
   pargs = pargs + 1;
  }
 }
 putchar('\n');
 for(nargs = pargs - hargs, i = 0; i < nargs; ++i)
  printf("%d arg is: %.*s\n", i, hargs[i].l, hargs[i].p);
 qsort(hargs, nargs, sizeof(struct pp), cmp);
 putchar('\n');
 for(i = 0; i < nargs; ++i)
  printf("%d arg is: %.*s\n", i, hargs[i].l, hargs[i].p);

 return 0;
}
```

https://rextester.com/GSH22767

Comment: This is a good solution if you don't want to copy the strings. Shouldn't you take into account the `pv1->l` in `cmp`?

Comment: @NeilEdelman I've thought about it. Since only length of a second string can be greater length, one may modify the cmp function to take it into account. Should I suppose that if left string equals to right, and, right string is greater, then, cmp shall return +1 ?

Comment: In general, `cmp` could be called on any string, so I think that if `strncmp` (size smaller) returns 0, if it's different lengths, you should just return the one that is longer.

Answer (score 0):

Upon splitting a `C` string, one needs one extra `char` to store extra null-terminator. There is one answer that bypasses this by storing the length. For completeness, this is closer to your original intention: allocating enough space to copy the programmes arguments. It probably works slower, but one is free to use the strings elsewhere in the programme.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc free EXIT qsort */
#include <stdio.h>  /* fprintf */
#include <string.h> /* strlen memcpy */
#include <errno.h>  /* errno */

static int strcompare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const char *a_str = *(const char *const*)a, *b_str = *(const char *const*)b;
    return strcmp(a_str, b_str);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *spacev = 0, **listv = 0;
    size_t spacec = 0, listc = 0;
    int is_done = 0;
    do { /* "Try." */
        int i;
        char *sv;
        size_t j;
        /* This requires argc > 1. */
        if(argc <= 1) { errno = EDOM; break; }
        /* Allocate maximum space. */
        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) spacec += strlen(argv[i]) + 2;
        if(!(spacev = malloc(spacec)) || !(listv = malloc(argc * 2))) break;
        sv = spacev;
        /* Copy and split the arguments. */
        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            const char *const word = argv[i];
            const size_t word_len = strlen(word),
                w0_len = word_len / 2, w1_len = word_len - w0_len;
            if(w0_len) {
                listv[listc++] = sv;
                memcpy(sv, word, w0_len);
                sv += w0_len;
                *(sv++) = '\0';
            }
            if(w1_len) {
                listv[listc++] = sv;
                memcpy(sv, word + w0_len, w1_len);
                sv += w1_len;
                *(sv++) = '\0';
            }
        }
        /* Sort. */
        qsort(listv, listc, sizeof listv, &strcompare);
        for(j = 0; j < listc; j++) printf("%s\n", listv[j]);
        is_done = 1;
    } while(0); if(!is_done) {
        perror("split");
    } {
        free(spacev);
        free(listv);
    }
    return is_done ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

It is simpler than your original; instead of allocating each string individually, it counts the maximum number of `char`s needed (plus two for two null terminators) and allocates the block all at once (`space`.) The pointers to the new list also need allocating, the maximum is `2 * argc`. Once you copy and modify the argument list, one has an actual array of strings that one can `qsort`.